# Why does this motherboard report "no VGA" with one processor, yet works fine with another?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I have an Asus prime B450M-A motherboard and an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 CPU, and a discrete video card (a GTX 750i). When I boot it up, I get a beep code of one long and three short beeps, which the manual tells me is a "No VGA detected" error. If I replace the CPU with an AMD Athlon 200GE processor, the system boots up fine. The Athlon has onboard graphics and the Ryzen doesn't, but when I boot up on the Athlon, it's using my discrete graphics card. I've used a replacement Ryzen CPU, but the same problem persists. What could be causing this?

Edit: the UEFI BIOS is updated to version 1607, which is supposedly the latest version, according to Asus.

Comment: You have upgraded the firmware on the motherboard?

Comment: I have, yes. Using the Athlon.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Done, thank you.